# SQL Server 2014, how to extract apartment unit value from end of string

Tags: sql-server, string, text-extraction

I need to compare parts of an address. I am breaking the address string into smaller parts such as house number, street direction, street name, unit number, street type. I have most of the parts ready, but I am having trouble at extracting the unit number, or letter from the end of the string.

I have identified the following cases:

```
3015 NESSLING ST            < no unit value, no need to do anything
6941 CHESTER DR # H         < alpha value with space after the # sign need the H
6941 CHESTER DR #B          < alpha value with no space after the # sign, need the B
7203 MID TOWN RD # 209      < numeric value after the # sign and space in between, need the 209
3100 LAKE MENDOTA DR #802   < numeric value after the # sign and no space in between, need the 802
6949 CHESTER DR UNIT C      < non numeric value after word UNIT, need the C
6949 CHESTER DR UNITC       < alpha value after word UNIT with no space in between, need the C
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 207   < numeric value after the word UNIT with space in between, need the 207
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207    < numeric value after the word UNIT no space in between, need the 207
```

I think, looking at the records that need to have their address  corrected, these are all the cases I see.

Is it possible to retrieve the values specified above using SQL?

I tried the follow:

```
DECLARE @textval NVARCHAR(30)

SET @textval = '7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@textval,PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',@textval)+1,PATINDEX('%[0-9],%',@textval+ ',')-PATINDEX('% [0-9]%',@textval))


3015 NESSLING ST            - works, returns blank
6941 CHESTER DR # H         - does not work, returns blank
6941 CHESTER DR #B          - does not work, returns blank
7203 MID TOWN RD # 209      - works, returns 209
3100 LAKE MENDOTA DR #802   - does not work, returns 3100 LAKE MENDOTA DR #802
6949 CHESTER DR UNIT C      - does not work, returns blank, should return C
6949 CHESTER DR UNITC       - does not work, returns blank, should return C
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 207   - works, returns 207
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 207   - does not work, returns 7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207
```

Any help would be great.

Many thanks in advance.

***UPDATE using Ryan's proposed solution:***

```
DECLARE @textval NVARCHAR(30)

SET @textval = '7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207'


SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CHARINDEX('#', @textval) > -1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@textval, CHARINDEX('#', @textval) + 1, LEN(@textval)-(CHARINDEX('#', @textval)+1)))
        WHEN CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) > -1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@textval, CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) + 1, LEN(@textval)-(CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval)+1)))
        ELSE ''
    END AS [UnitValue];

/*
3015 NESSLING ST            - does not work, returns 3015 NESSLING S
6941 CHESTER DR # H         - does not work, returns blank
6941 CHESTER DR #B          - does not work, returns blank
7203 MID TOWN RD # 209      - does not work, returns 20
3100 LAKE MENDOTA DR #802   - does not work, returns 80
6949 CHESTER DR UNIT C      - does not work, returns 6949 CHESTER DR UNIT
6949 CHESTER DR UNITC       - does not work, returns 6949 CHESTER DR UNIT
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 207   - works, returns 7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 20
7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207    - does not work, returns 7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT20
*/
```

Comment: I had a few additions wrong in my answer, I just tested it and it should work now.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I had some of the addition wrong and CHARINDEX returns 0 if not found not -1, sorry for the confusion. I tested this in SQL Server 2014 for case with # and case with UNIT and both worked with the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do what you want

```
--Check if Address contains # or UNIT if so, Left Trim the whitespace
--Off of the substring value to remove the white space ones
--And get the remaining string value    

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('#', [Address]) > 0 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING([Address], CHARINDEX('#', [Address])
+ 1, LEN([Address]) - (CHARINDEX('#', [Address])))) WHEN CHARINDEX('UNIT', [Address])
 > 0 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING([Address], CHARINDEX('UNIT', [Address]) + 4, LEN([Address]) - 
(CHARINDEX('UNIT', [Address])))) ELSE '' END AS [UnitValue]
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, trying to use your code, but I get an error for the CHARINDEX function, it tells me that it requires 2 arguments. I changed the second WHEN from: WHEN CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) > -1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@textval, CHARINDEX('UNIT') + 1, LEN(@textval) - (CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) + 1)))  to: WHEN CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) > -1 THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@textval, CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval) + 1, LEN(@textval)-(CHARINDEX('UNIT', @textval)+1))). COuld you tell me if that is correct? Thank you.

Comment: @erasmocarlos I neglected to fill in one of the CHARINDEX() calls with the second param, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

based on the examples, the rules can be simplified to below:

1. Find # or unit in string
2. If not found, return with no action
3. If found, then find the first word after and extract

This can be achieved with a combination of string operations

```
SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX(address, ' ') > 0,  SUBSTRING(a.TrimmedAddress, 1, CHARINDEX(a.TrimmedAddress, ' ')), a.TrimmedAddress) AS 'UnitNumber'
FROM (
    SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX(address, '#') > 0,  
           LTRIM(RIGHT(address, CHARINDEX(address, '#') + 1))，
           IIF(CHARINDEX(address, 'unit') > 0, LTRIM(RIGHT(address,CHARINDEX(address, '#') + 1))，'') AS 'TrimmedAddress'
    ) FROM address) a
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming there are no major differences in your data:

```
;WITH CTE (Column1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('3015 NESSLING ST'), 
            ('6941 CHESTER DR # H'), 
            ('6941 CHESTER DR #B'), 
            ('7203 MID TOWN RD # 209'), 
            ('3100 LAKE MENDOTA DR #802'), 
            ('6949 CHESTER DR UNIT C'), 
            ('6949 CHESTER DR UNITC'), 
            ('7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT 207'), 
            ('7203 MID TOWN RD UNIT207')
    ) AS A (Column1)
)

SELECT CASE 
    WHEN PATINDEX('%#%', Column1) > 0
        THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('#', Column1) + 1, LEN(Column1) - (CHARINDEX('#', Column1))))
    WHEN PATINDEX('%UNIT%', Column1) > 0
        THEN LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX('UNIT', Column1) + 4, LEN(Column1) - (CHARINDEX('UNIT', Column1))))
    ELSE 
        Column1
    END AS Result
FROM CTE
```